# YouTube Analytics - when to stop querying?

Tags: youtube-api

A quick overview of what my application is doing:

1. A customer authenticates their Google account via OAuth.
2. I retrieve their access and refresh tokens and store them for use
3. I make a YouTube Analytics report query for basic metrics such as views, comments, etc..  I query starting from today, and go backwards in time.

My question is: How do I know when to stop querying?

The API doesn't appear to return any errors even if I specify a date from 1980.  The API does seem to return no results in that the "rows" field is not present:

{"kind":"youtubeAnalytics#resultTable","columnHeaders":[{"name":"day","columnType":"DIMENSION","dataType":"STRING"},{"name":"views","columnType":"METRIC","dataType":"INTEGER"}]}

Is it reliable for me to stop querying if the API returns a result like this where the "rows" field is not-present?  My concern is if the customer doesn't have any data for a certain period, and the API returns this type of result (missing "rows" field), is it possible that the customer still has data prior to his time period?  Thus I should continue querying backwards?  How do I know when to stop?

Answer (score 0):

YouTube launched in February 2005, so you at least never have to query for dates before that :)

However, it seems like days without any views will return 0 views, and days before a video or channel existed will not return a row, so you should be safe to stop when no more rows are returned.

But instead of querying day by day, why don't you query for the whole date interval you are interested in and thus only make one query? With start-date=2005-01-01 and end-date={$today} and dimensions=day?

My video that recently got uploaded, with *very* limited number of views:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/analytics/v1/reports?ids=channel%3D%3DYHMS8hN8s49F93iJuEgG6w&start-date=2005-01-01&end-date=2013-01-21&metrics=views%2Ccomments&dimensions=day&filters=video%3D%3D_iwmv6644dA&sort=day&key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

Response:

```
{
  "kind": "youtubeAnalytics#resultTable",
  "columnHeaders": [
    {
      "name": "day",
      "columnType": "DIMENSION",
      "dataType": "STRING"
    }, {
      "name": "views",
      "columnType": "METRIC",
      "dataType": "INTEGER"
    }
  ],
  "rows": [
    ["2013-01-07", 1],
    ["2013-01-08", 0],
    ["2013-01-09", 0],
    ["2013-01-10", 0],
    ["2013-01-11", 0],
    ["2013-01-12", 1],
    ["2013-01-13", 0],
    ["2013-01-14", 1],
    ["2013-01-15", 0],
    ["2013-01-16", 0]
    ["2013-01-17", 0],
    ["2013-01-18", 0],
    ["2013-01-19", 0],
  ]
}
```

btw, I used the API Explorer to try this out: https://developers.google.com/youtube/analytics/v1/